# In the universe of John Carter and "A Princess of Mars" light plays a role. Why?

Tags: mars, barsoom

In the *John Carter* universe, the energy source is all about light waves. Light ships float on light waves, and different light waves unlocks energies unknown to men.

My question is: Was Mr. Burroughs inspired by anything that we know about at the time? Theories? Pseudoscience? The first discovery of solar panels 1883?

Most sci-fi works play on science, theories and sometimes pseudoscience, *Star Trek's* warp drives to take one example. In the classic work *Journey to the Center of the Earth* it becomes apparent in the book that this was a very shallow theory and they are surprised that they are not cooking far down in the Earth.

Answer (score 28):

**Rays were a hot topic at the time**

I can't find any reference to Burroughs' inspiration for his light-based technology, but modern science at the time he wrote (1911-12) it was very much focused on rays:

- Radio waves were discovered in 1886 and first used to communicate across the Atlantic in 1895
- X-rays were discovered in 1895
- Alpha, beta and gamma radiation were discovered ca. 1900
- Einstein's theory of special relativity, with its focus on the speed of light, was  published in 1905.

At the time, it must have seemed to a layman like Burroughs that new and exciting rays of light, with each their own extraordinary property, were discovered all the time. Burroughs was by no means alone in this; early pulp science fiction abounded with all sorts of strange rays.

Comment: I'm not certain that Mr. Burroughs had a clear understanding of how radiation worked. He described his Barsoom airships as flying on buoyancy tanks filled with the 'ray of repulsion'.

Comment: I think you will find that Sci Fi still does abound in strange rays - light sabres, photon torpedoes, tractor beams, phasers (though I'm aware that Star Trek is old so tradition must be maintained...) to name a few.

Comment: Also relevant from that era: the debate over [N-rays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-ray).

Comment: And in Burroughs' book on Venus, he uses the **r-rays** ...

Comment: Don't forget cathode rays (or electrons, as we know them)

Comment: Those poor benighted primitives with their magic rays.  We moderns know that _beams_ are where it's really at.